# IIS Express - localhost - authentication - unauthorized

Tags: express, iis, localhost, unauthorized

Visual Studio 2017 and 2022
Windows 11

Perhaps something was changed in my local environment by my organization's IT...
Ctrl-F5 launches app on localhost as usual, but I am prompted for authentication credentials...
My normal account, with which I am logged onto Windows is "Unauthorized"...

Many hours have been spent attempting to resolve the issue, without success.

**Web config file contains:**

`<system.web> <authentication mode="Windows"/> </system.web>`

**/.vs/config/ applicationhost.config  contains:**

`<authentication> <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" /> <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" /> </authentication>`

Thank you in advance for your time and for any support.

EDIT:
Uninstalled:  VS 2017, VS 2022, IIS Express
Installed: VS 2022
The issue persists.

=============== ERROR PAGE ==============

HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

Most likely causes:
No authentication protocol (including anonymous) is selected in IIS.
Only integrated authentication is enabled, and a client browser was used that does not support integrated authentication.
Integrated authentication is enabled and the request was sent through a proxy that changed the authentication headers before they reach the Web server.
The Web server is not configured for anonymous access and a required authorization header was not received.
The "configuration/system.webServer/authorization" configuration section may be explicitly denying the user access.

Things you can try:
Verify the authentication setting for the resource and then try requesting the resource using that authentication method.
Verify that the client browser supports Integrated authentication.
Verify that the request is not going through a proxy when Integrated authentication is used.
Verify that the user is not explicitly denied access in the "configuration/system.webServer/authorization" configuration section.
Check the failed request tracing logs for additional information about this error. For more information, click here.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       AuthenticateRequest
Handler    ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code     0x80070005
Requested URL      http://localhost:1025/Event/Home
Physical Path      C:_git\ipec-healthcare-acquired-infections\HAI\Event\Home
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined

More Information:
This error occurs when the WWW-Authenticate header sent to the Web server is not supported by the server configuration. Check the authentication method for the resource, and verify which authentication method the client used. The error occurs when the authentication methods are different. To determine which type of authentication the client is using, check the authentication settings for the client.
View more information »

Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

907273
253667

Comment: Don't want to oversimplify this, but VS2017/VS2022 use different config files https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#add-iis-express-from-visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-solution-file So anyone here will have to access your machine so as to tell what might be wrong.

Comment: If your organization's IT department have made changes to Group Policy settings, this may affect how Windows authentication works on your machine. You can check Group Policy Settings by running gpedit.msc from the Run dialog (Windows Key + R) and navigating to Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options. Look for policies related to network authentication.